# Compose test - click outside a composable

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, android-jetpack-compose

Hi we want to test the behavior of our *ModalBottomSheet* when the user clicks outside. In that case our bottom sheet closes.

Does anybody know how we can test sth like a "click outside" of a composable?

```
@Test
fun contentState_dismissed(){
    // given
    val state = createContentState()
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        WegpunktScreen(
            state = state,
            onDismissClicked = {}
        )
    }
    
    // when
    val bottomSheet = composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(BOTTOM_SHEET)
    // HERE we want to click outside the composable, not on the composable
    bottomSheet.performClick()

    // then
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(BOTTOM_SHEET).assertIsNotDisplayed()
}
```

Comment: Wrap WegpunktScreen in another composable inside the test, click that, assert that WegpunktScreen (or one of its children) is no longer visible

Comment: Awesome Idea, will test tomorrow!